# CSS in Flask WTforms works on button but not for others

Tags: python, css, flask, bootstrap-4, flask-wtforms

```
{% extends "layout.html"%}
{%block contents%}
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{form.hidden_tag()}}
        <div class="container">
            {{form.username.label(class_="label-txt")}}
            {{form.username(class_="label")}}
        </div>
        {{form.submit(class_="btn")}}
{%endblock contents%}
```

The above sign up page has submit button with the css which works fine but for the username field it is not working.
If i pass the same class for username it is working.
Very confusing, no CSS is working for the fields.

CSS:

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  background: rgb(220,220,220);
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(120,120,120);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #8BC34A;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.label-txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.6em;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: rgb(120,120,120);
  transition: ease .3s;
}
.label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px 0px;
}
.input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

[image: CSS for btn works not the username field]

Comment: remove '<div class="container">' and see the magic... :P

Comment: also, you don't need to write {% endblock contents%} , {% endblock %} is enough...

Comment: yeah for the end block, just for my understanding which block  I'm closing :)
Will check the  container and check now.

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha no luck bro, not working :( infact the submit btn css works inside  container as well

Answer (score 0):

It looks you did everything right. The only thing that is causing a problem is your css on label-txt. Just take out `position: absolute` and see.

Assuming you have linked css file properly on your layout.html
`url_for('static', filename='main.css')`, you can see the class you added by inspecting the tag